# Normal cumulative distribution for C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, cumulative-sum

I am trying to convert the following mathematical equation from the expression normal cumulative distribution into C# in Unity. NORMSDIST is the expression used in Excel through which I thought if this could be done in C#. So is there a simplified way of this equation?

[image: Cumulative]

NORMSDIST (-0.48) = 0.31

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing to be honest. I still do not know if there is a way to even do this in C#.

Comment: I'm no math expert, but are all the things on the right side of the equals either constants or `x`? If so, just build the formula in code and plug in for `x`?

Comment: You could try distributions from https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/, gaussian is there

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the comments. I achieved this using `using MathNet.Numerics;`. You can download this package for Unity by installing NuGet - https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity.

Hence, the following worked:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MathNet.Numerics;
using UnityEngine;

public class CumulativeFunction : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start () {
        F (-0.48f);
    }

    static double F (double x) {
        MathNet.Numerics.Distributions.Normal result = new MathNet.Numerics.Distributions.Normal ();
        return result.CumulativeDistribution (x);

    }

}
```